# Syntax highlighting (in Emacs) for SQL code in log files

Tags: emacs, syntax, syntax-highlighting, highlight

How can we highlight SQL code in some log files, with Emacs?

Sample log file:

```
[DEBUG][2016-05-26 09:04:51,714][FileHelper] - [realContextPath=[/server.xml]]
[DEBUG][2016-05-26 10:24:22,369][DbConnectionImpl] - [DELETE FROM xct_log]
[DEBUG][2016-05-26 11:00:46,925][DataSourceRestrictionConverter] - [parseRestrictions]
[DEBUG][2016-05-26 10:24:22,476][DbConnectionImpl] - [UPDATE hlpdsk_step_log
SET table_name= 'hxct_log' WHERE
 table_name='xct_log' AND pkey_value = 247296]
```

The goal would be to put a light yellow background behind SQL code, that is:

- code found between the last [...] (can be on multiple physical lines, as shown in the last line of the log sample), and
- code found on lines where the "source" (3rd bracket pair) is "DbConnectionImpl".

If possible, the yellow background should only be between those last 2 brackets, on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is Emacs, I am sure what you want is possible,but it seems like it would require a lot of custom elisp code, that I won't be able to provide.

What I have done in similar situations, is just use `M-x sql-mode` to put the whole buffer in `sql-mode`. This way all your SQL keywords will be highlighted and most everything else will remain the default text color. All your SQL code should stand out when you are scanning your log files (which I assume is your end goal).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Though, the problem is I'm only interested by SQL code in the lines "DbConnectionImpl" -- and there is as well much (almost duplicated) SQL code in other log lines (which I can't disable).

Comment: @user3341592 got it. Well, I hope you find a solution. Try moving this question to [emacs.stackexchange.com](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/) if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Posted on http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/syntax-highlighting-in-emacs-for-sql-code-in-log-files.